# Manage dotfiles merge conflicts in git config without breaking git

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, dotfiles

I manage my config files in a git repository in `~/.dotfiles` and deploy them with `stow`.

Sometimes I come across errors like:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: tmux: put newer version commands inside if-block
fatal: bad config line 149 in file /home/ravi/.config/git/config
Cannot store 5639c86778d99ec6b34c93bfd4d122c1cbb379a8
```

`git` is complaining because its config file has bad syntax - because of a yet unresolved merge conflict, the config file now includes lines like:

```
<<<<<<< A
lines in file A
=======
lines in file B
>>>>>>> B
```

Every time this happens I need to:

1. `git rebase --abort`
2. `cp ~/.config/git/config ~/.gitconfig` (`.gitconfig` is used preferentially)
3. Complete the operation that had the initial failure
4. Remember to delete `~/.gitconfig`

How can I automate the config copy to `~/.gitconfig` and subsequent removal?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting problem.

I recommend avoiding it. :-)

I keep a set of dot-files (including a `$HOME/.gitconfig` file) in a Git repository, but I don't use this Git repository's work-tree as the actual dot-files.<sup>1</sup>  Hence, if conflicts occur, they don't affect the actual dot-files.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is only true on some systems, but I avoid merging on systems where a home-directory dot-file is a hard or symbolic link to a dotfiles-work-tree copy.